# remove first row in MySQL SELECT without using OFFSET

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a pyspark SQL script, which is supposed to remove the first row in SQL SELECT.

But pyspark SQL seems does not support OFFSET as it shows EOF error for OFFSET.

How could I remove the first row in pyspark SELECT ?

```
sdfData = scSpark.read.csv(data_file, header=True, sep=",", encoding='UTF-8').cache()


sdfData.registerTempTable("books")

scSpark.sql('SELECT `Course Name` AS title, `Discipline Code` AS discipline_code FROM books')
```

The above query contains table header, which is not supposed to be saved to MySQL.

I have to keep the header in dataframe so can select some columns based on header in the later spark SQL. What I really need is removing the header in the spark SQL (the last line) as I have to import the selected data into the MySQL DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually header=True removes the header row so that should have worked still you can try using below code to remove first row

```
df2=df.first()
df=df.exceptAll(spark.createDataFrame([df2]))
```

You can read about exceptAll [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll.html)

Comment: where should I insert this data. I do not have a dataframe in my script, I only have SparkSession in my code

Comment: If I understood correctly then you wanted to remove the first row from the sdfData dataframe right

Comment: No, I have to keep the header in dataframe so can select some column based on header in the later spark SQL.  What I really need is removing the header in the spark SQL (last line)  as I have to import the selected data into the MySQL DB

Comment: Looking at your code the last line is just a view on top of the sdfData dataframe so if you perform the above operations before registering the sdfData as books table probably you won't see the first header row that you are speaking of, Also which version of spark are you using cause registerTempTable was deprecated in spark 2.0 so suggest you to use newer version if possible

Comment: Just tried, not working, ValueError: '_jdf' is not in list

Comment: Yeah sorry passed row directly , I have fixed code now